# Sparse matrix in LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a small LSTM model for binary classification with `tf-idf` transformation. And I am getting this warning and it's taking a long time to train:

> **UserWarning:** Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
>     "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

My code looks like this

```
xtrain_tfv = tfv.transform(xtrain)
xvalid_tfv = tfv.transform(xvalid)
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(xtrain_tfv.shape[0], 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(xtrain_tfv, ytrain,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=15,
          validation_data=(xvalid_tfv, yvalid))
score, acc = model.evaluate(xtest_tfv, ytest,
                            batch_size=32)
```

`xtrain_tfv` has a shape of `(6851, 9122)`
. How to handle this?

Comment: Can you share sample data? And how large is your vocabulary?

Comment: Also, why are you using tf-idf when you have an Embedding layer? What are you planning to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @thushv89 . I think I have mistakenly used tf-idf instead of 'one hot'. I am pretty beginner in the field. Sorry for posting with wrong codes.

Comment: All good. Happy to help :)

Comment: Should I take it down ?

Comment: No, that's okay you can leave it as it is. Someone might find it useful.

Comment: @mmrbulbul: Can you please confirm if using `tf-idf` instead of `one hot` has resolved your issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the warning if the process which you are doing is not causing the slowness of the model.

The warning can be explained as below.

```
# dense
array = ['a', None, None, 'c']

# sparse
array = [(0, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
```

So as you can see if you have a lot of empty entries a sparse array will be much more efficient than a dense one. But if all entries are filled in, dense is far more efficient. In your case somewhere in the tensor flow graph a sparse array is being converted to a dense one of indeterminate size. The warning is just saying it is possible that you can waste a lot of memory like this. But it might not be a problem at all if the sparse array is not too big/already quite dense.

You have mentioned that you have solved the issue using one-hot encoding. But if your vocabulary size is large, one-hot encoding is not suggested since it creates sparse matrix of large dimension.

You can follow the below method to convert your text data into sequences of same length.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
# prepare tokenizer
t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts(token_list) 
vocab_size = 10000 # depends on your data
# integer encode the documents
encoded_docs = t.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
max_length = max_len
X = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
```

For embedding layer, you can use pre-trained word embeddings which will create a desnse vector.You can follow this [Tensorflow's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/graph_keras_lstm_imdb#create_sample_embeddings) for the same.